# The virtual terminal is automatically disabled

Tags: c, shell, terminal, command-line-interface, ansi-escape

I'm trying to make a command line application using the C programming language. However, when the ANSI color codes are working correctly, somehow the virtual terminal processing turns off and the color codes start to look as if they are text. When I clean the console the problem is fixed but there is no way to do it without cleaning it?

```
printf("\033[1;92m");
printf("%s","TEST");
printf("\033[0m");
```

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Without seeing your code, it is nigh impossible to help you.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for how to phrase your question.

Comment: Just brainstorming ... does the terminal processing turn off when you write after the right hand margin, the bottom margin (after scrolling perhaps)?

Comment: No, but for example I'm entering the git push command. It shuts down after that command.

Comment: If you want to play with colours etc on a windows console, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference The ANSI escape codes don't always work

Comment: I solved my problem by pulling windows.h and enabling virtual terminal processing.